# How are Launchpad teams usually formed?

Tags: application-development, launchpad

Over time, I answered a number of questions here. Many times, these questions were quite (user) specific and answers were created, writing in an improvising way.
In some occasions however, things were definitely more developed into a mature result. Some of *these* questions/answers furthermore, might be useful to a broader range of users, with a nicely integrated GUI, be maintained, updated and easily available and installable by inexperienced users.

Specifically, I am thinking of combining (some) of these posts into a easily accessible set of *workspace tools* or whatever the name would be: [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/676089/72216), [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/608295/72216), [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/560734/72216), maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/742407/72216), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/601572/72216) one.

Although I *love* to update these answers every now and then here, like anyone else I have my limitations (won't tell you which :) ), and a one-person team is not the most professional approach to guarantee a long(er) life of a project.

So my question is: ***how are launchpad teams usually created***

---

#### EDIT

#### Narrowing down the question a bit

I get the impression many users of AU, actively involved in developing, are also programmers/developers in their daily live. Their daily environment is more or less related to what they do here.

With me the situation is quite different. Most of my colleagues do not know *at all* what I am doing here, have little understanding of-, and no affinity with the subject. In other words; my professional network is not related to programming *at all*.

The most important insight I'd like to gain is if teams (in general) come from *existing* co operations, brought to Launchpad, or if new teams arise in the virtual world.

Comment: Nice idea, I also considered uploading all the scripts from my answers somewhere. I even created a PPA once, but never had enough time and motivation to sit down and learn how to package them properly. So I just started a GitHub Team (with me as only member at the moment) and uploaded (only one yet) script there... But if more people would like to join and make a common Ask Ubuntu answer scripts repository or PPA, that would be cool and a nice motivation to continue.

Comment: @kos initially, I kind of agreed, the fact that I even couldn't find an appropriate tag made me worry a bit. On the other hand: although it is not directly *about* AU, it is related in the sense that it is definitely related to what we do here. Also:  *Ask Ubuntu is a question and answer site for Ubuntu users and developers* ...

Comment: Way too broad - it can't be answered within the scope of the site I believe.

Comment: @ThomasW. I am pretty sure a useful answer to get the direction can be given, not only for me. I am not asking for a magic formula, just one or more useful hints on how it works in practice. Many of us have a software-development related background I assume, and/or are involved in *teams* on Launchpad. I am active on Launchpad, but only on "solo" projects.

Comment: Ubuntu Wiki can be used as a media too. If you are developing some tool, make a PPA+github mirror: the team will start to appear if someone tries to improve your tool. Then the tool can be integrated into default Ubuntu if it's very useful. Alternatively, you can submit bugreports/feature-requests to Launchpad for the existing modules (to know if your change will be supported), and then send some code.

Comment: Except teams are teams - on solo projects they are used for different aspects of a project; for teams that are more social or to show something other than project affiliation they are whatever you want them to be.  As I stated the number of uses and explanations is impossible to fit into the scope of this site's requirements for Q/A

Comment: @ThomasW. Obviously, I don't agree.

Comment: Why not simply create a `.deb` file for it and try publishing it via `Software Center` ?   Call it something like `unity-workspace-tools` and submit to Canonical for approval .  That will give the users simplicity of just running ` sudo apt-get install unity-workspace-tools` and that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would flag it, too broad! I lack the experience to cover many aspects. I salute you because you have special finger print on your answers as the those you have mentioned. Those are really prototypes made here as answers.

Free Softwares are built by free community. Large softwares have solid core either one, two or many developers. The core team is generally built in real life (social relations+topic interest) or few virtually (topic interest).

I look to those prototypes as separate projects, each is belongs to you as developer & (OP + Some up voters) as users.

At this point forget about the team, you are the core and you will be so and so as the project get bigger and complicated. Those in the virtual team, they will come & go without a notice, most of them they may never contribute code, at best they will submit a bug.

blaa blaa I can continue talking ... kind of experience resume without much benefits. Try collecting some interest in those projects, and see if it is worthy.

1. Create a repository on a social git site, popular one MR. Octopus GitHub.
2. Update your answer and a link to your new upstream project (keep original code)
3. Create a mirror project on Launchpad.
4. Prepare Debian packaging
5. Publish a PPA
6. Update your answer again and add *another* link to PPA.

So now basically you have upstream project development on GitHub & binary releases on Launchpad. After this, [Que Sera, Sera (Whatever Will Be, Will Be)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Que_Sera,_Sera_%28Whatever_Will_Be,_Will_Be%29). I just wish you best luck :D.

I have a answer here that I promoted it to a very <sup>very</sup><sub>tiny</sub> projecto.

Time for another Ads ;)

- AU Q: [How to add a keyboard modifier state applet to Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402315/how-to-add-a-keyboard-modifier-state-applet-to-unity-panel/)
- GitHub: https://github.com/sneetsher/indicator-xkbmod
- Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/indicator-xkbmod
- PPA: https://code.launchpad.net/~sneetsher/+archive/ubuntu/one

Btw, If you are trying to make a handover that's will not work. People care only about what they really need and they evaluate it how it's worth before they put some time in it.