# Is there some timer on workspaces?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces

I'm using multiple workspaces on Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to have a timer on each one of them to know how much I am on each one. To describe it more, normally I use WS1 for work WS2 for communication WS3 for fun and WS4 for other work. And to avoid multitasking and procrastination I think it would be a good tool to know how much time I spend and where do I spend it.

Comment: Interesting. Please look at this one https://askubuntu.com/a/601572/72216, is that what you are looking for? It is for Unity though, needs some editing (and modernizing :) )to work for mutter. I will if you confirm that's what you are looking for.

Comment: BTW, are you using dynamic workspaces (I hope not)?

Comment: Just curious, but still interested in your own question? ^^^